# can @Valid annotation check on fields recursively in spring mvc?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I make a model object with some JSR-303 validator annotation:

```
public class UserInfoBasicModel  implements Serializable{
    @NotNull(message="cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message="cannot be empty")
    private String name;
    //getter and setter
    //..ignored..
}
```

Auto data-binding it in a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController  {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registry/")
    public String registry(HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap modelMap,
            @Valid UserInfoBasicModel userInfoBasicModel,
            BindingResult result)    {
        //...some code here...
    }
}
```

In the above scenario, it works fine for the validation. But when I encapsulate the model into another object just as below, the validation on UserInfoBasicModel doesn't work anymore:

the Object that encapsulates the UserInfoBasicModel object:

```
public static class UserUpdateFormTransmitter       {
    @Valid
    private UserInfoBasicModel userInfoBasicModel;
    //getter and setter
    //..ignored..
}
```

the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController  {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registry/")
    public String registry(HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap modelMap,
            @Valid UserUpdateFormTransmitter userUpdateFormTransmitter,
            BindingResult result)    {
        //...some code here...
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why doesn't the @valid annotaion works recursively just like what [JSR 303: Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine-graphvalidation) says.Could any one give me a solution so that I can valid my object recursively, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Maybe the second valid can be omitted? The first Valid should cascade through the entire model.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar with Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, and adding `@Valid` to my equivalent to your `userInfoBasicModel` in `UserUpdateFormTransmitter` got it working for me. Without it, nested validation was ignored.

Answer (score 7):

I have never done recursive validation, but according to [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/bean-validation-jsr-303-annotations-apache-myfaces-1.2) its possible simply by tagging the sub-objects with @Valid.

Comment: It works like that, but it is an awful cheap workaround and I also not like it.

Answer (score -1):

My two cents:

1.Try using ModelAttribute like below:

Java file:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registry/")
public String registry(HttpServletRequest request,
            ModelMap modelMap,
            @ModelAttribute("userupdate") @Valid UserUpdateFormTransmitter userUpdateFormTransmitter,
            BindingResult result)
```

JSP:

```
<form:form method="POST" name="form1" action="/registry" modelAttribute="userupdate">
```

2.Ensure that you are using path attribute like

```
//for recursive access
<form:input type="text" id="name" path="userInfoBasicModel.name" />
```

instead of

```
<form:input type="text" id="name" value="${userInfoBasicModel.name}" />
```